# Aerospike - Check/Increment for NIL value in a list?

Tags: java, aerospike

If I run this code, it increments whatever the value is present at Index 7, if any of the index before 7 are not present, it simply puts NIL as its value

**Code**

```
Operation operation = ListOperation.increment( "incre", 7 );
client.operate( policy, key, operation );
```

**AQL**

```
aql> select * from test.users
+----+----------------------------------------+
| PK | incre                                  |
+----+----------------------------------------+
| 2  | LIST('[1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, NIL, 1]') |
+----+----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.095 secs)
```

As you can see, index 6 didn't exist, so aerospike automatically put NIL in its place.
If I try to increment index 6, I get this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException: Error 4,1,30000,0,0,BB955892AFD8CA0 127.0.0.1 3000: Parameter error
```

My questions :-

1) Is it possible to put any sort of default value instead of NIL for indexes which dont exist? If there is no way to check for NIL, is it possible to increment NIL?

2) Is there a way to check for NIL value before incrementing it?

Comment: You can prevent inserting past the boundary of a current list value with a boundary list write flag in the list operation policy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Increment operation assumes that the data type is integer. So, when you try to increment at position 7, and there is no element there yet, it starts with integer 0 and increments to 1. However, as you noticed, 6th position is filled with NIL as the list needs to be continuous. Now the problem is that NIL is not an integer. So, you cannot increment it.

To answer your specific questions:

1. No, it is not possible to fill with a specific default value.
2. You can read the element at a position you can use the getType() of the Value class to know if the element is null type.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid upserting such a list by using the  `LIST_WRITE_INSERT_BOUNDED` flag as part of your list operation's policy. That kind of operation would throw a specific error code 26. For example (Python):

```py
from __future__ import print_function
import aerospike
import sys
from aerospike_helpers.operations import list_operations as lh

config = {"hosts": [("127.0.0.1", 3000)]}

try:
    client = aerospike.client(config).connect()
except e.ClientError:
    print("Error: {0} [{1}]".format(e.msg, e.code))
    sys.exit(1)

key = ("test", "example", "here")

try:
    client.remove(key)
except:
    pass

try:
    ops = [
        # increment the seventh element of a non-existent record with boundary
        # restriction
        lh.list_increment(
            "incre", 7, 2, {"write_flags": aerospike.LIST_WRITE_INSERT_BOUNDED}
        )
    ]
    k, m, b = client.operate(key, ops)
except Exception as e:
    print("Error: {0} [{1}]".format(e.msg, e.code))
    print("Could not increment outside the boundary, in this case no record\n")

# try again, without limit on inserting into the bounds of the list
try:
    ops = [
        # increment the seventh element of a non-existent record
        lh.list_increment(
            "incre", 7, 2, {}
        )
    ]
    k, m, b = client.operate(key, ops)
    (key, meta, bins) = client.get(key)
    print(bins)

    ops = [
        # increment the sixth element of the newly created record
        lh.list_increment(
            "incre", 6, 1, {}
        )
    ]
    k, m, b = client.operate(key, ops)
except Exception as e:
    print("Error: {0} [{1}]".format(e.msg, e.code))
    print("Can't increment a None (NIL) value\n")

client.close()
```

Which outputs

```
Error: 127.0.0.1:3000 AEROSPIKE_ERR_OP_NOT_APPLICABLE [26]
Could not increment outside the boundary, in this case no record

{'incre': [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 2]}
Error: 127.0.0.1:3000 AEROSPIKE_ERR_REQUEST_INVALID [4]
Can't increment a None (NIL) value
```

In the Java client this is [`ListWriteFlag.INSERT_BOUNDED`](https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/cdt/ListWriteFlags.html) flag to the [`ListPolicy`](https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/cdt/ListPolicy.html).

But really, if you have a tuple, where the positions 0th-6th have a specific meaning, you should initialize the bin with `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`.